# sql or sqlite query and getting result in a list

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am new to sql and In my app I am using sqlite DB's and I have trouble in creating a query.

I have a DB with column names to be:

```
Name1  Name2  Score1  Score2 Winner  Aces1  Aces2
```

Imagine that thse are the stats of a single game, so the same name can be in name 1 or in name 2 in different rows.

I want the following:

a)
Return in a list the player names with a descending number of aces.

For example imagine these rows:

```
Nick George 39  35  Nick  2   4
Joe  Nick   17  39  Nick  1   0
George Jorge  11  39  Jorge  3  1
```

Should give me in a list the following:
//number or aces

```
George 7
Nick 2
Joe 1
Jorge 1
```

b)I want the same with number of wins.

c)and the same avg points.

Can you please give me the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is a result of storing your data in a denormalised form. If you read up on [data normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), then you will store your data in a form that is more amenable to producing these queries easily.

```
select Winner, COUNT(*) from yourtable group by Winner order by COUNT(*) desc
```

and

```
select name, SUM(aces)
from
(
select Name1 as Name, Score1 as Score, Aces1 as Aces from yourtable
union all
select Name2 as Name, Score2 as Score, Aces2 as Aces from yourtable
) v
group by Name
order by SUM(aces) desc
```

Average points is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: just a question: in the second query the name has to be Name or something else? Because there is nothing declared as name? (Columns are Nmae1,Name2 and the equivalent name is Name).

Comment: In the inner query, the columns Name1 and Name2 are aliased as Name in `select Name1 as Name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

select name, SUM(aces)
from
(
select Name1 as Name, Score1 as Score, Aces1 as Aces from yourtable
union all
select Name2 as Name, Score2 as Score, Aces2 as Aces from yourtable
) v
group by Name
order by SUM(aces) desc